# Python unhashable type list inside JSON when refactored into a JSON array

Tags: python, arrays, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm generally aware of how python deals with JSON (I think), but I've come across something I can't explain.

I was initially using this code in an api endpoint to provide options for dropdown menus in a react app:

```
data = {
    "urgency_choices": URGENCY_CLASSES,
    "severity_choices": SEVERITY_CLASSES,
    "issue_classes": ISSUE_CLASSES,
    "flats": [(x.id, x.flat.name) for x in  OperationsFlat.objects.all()]
    }
```

I then decided that this could be refactored to instead provide a JSON array of 'fields', each with its own choices key, and whether or not it is a required field:

```
data = {
    [
        {"name": "Urgency", "choices": URGENCY_CLASSES, "required": True},
        {"name": "Severity", "choices": SEVERITY_CLASSES, "required": True},
        {"name": "Issue Class", "choices": ISSUE_CLASSES, "required": True},
        {"name": "Flat", "choices": [(x.id, x.flat.name) for x in  OperationsFlat.objects.all()], "required": True}
    ]
}
```

The error is:

```
"name": "Flat", "choices": [(x.id, x.flat.name) for x in  OperationsFlat.objects.all()], "required": True}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

To my mind, although the level of nesting of the list has changed, python still needs to hash the list in the same way, so why does it work in the first form, but not in the second?

More information:

This is within a django rest framework APIView, the APIView's return returns a Response object with this object in it.

Full TB, though I'm not sure how useful it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/.pyenv/versions/xenia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexanderhalford/work/nhuk/xenia/apps/operations/views.py", line 49, in get
    {"name": "Flat", "choices": {[(x.id, x.flat.name) for x in  OperationsFlat.objects.all()]}, "required": True}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: In your refactored example, the `data` variable is not a valid JSON. The `data` variable is a dictionary and the list inside it (which I assume is the `value`) has no `key`.

Comment: This is a `set`, not a `dict` ... and a set of one item (a `list`), hence your problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have a surrounding set of braces - `{ ... }` and then immediately inside you have square brackets - `[ ... ]`. This means that Python interprets your structure as a single *set*, to which you attempt to add a single item, which is a list - but lists cannot be hashed as they are mutable.

I don't know what format you actually want, but perhaps you meant to drop the braces altogether? Then indeed you would have a valid list of dicts.

```
data = [
    {"name": "Urgency", "choices": URGENCY_CLASSES, "required": True},
    {"name": "Severity", "choices": SEVERITY_CLASSES, "required": True},
    {"name": "Issue Class", "choices": ISSUE_CLASSES, "required": True},
    {"name": "Flat", "choices": [(x.id, x.flat.name) for x in  OperationsFlat.objects.all()], "required": True}
]
```

(or, perhaps, you meant to keep it as a dict containing a single item which is a list of dicts - but then you need a key: `data = {"data": [ ... ]}`.)

Comment: Oops... I should have spotted that. Thank you!